# Find $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ dx$ given $\int_{0}^{e^2} \frac{f(ln(\sqrt{x}))}{x}dx = 2e$.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Find $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ dx$ given $\int_{0}^{e^2} \frac{f(ln(\sqrt{x}))}{x}dx = 2e$.

**My attempt**

Make the substitution $u=\ln(\sqrt{x})$, then $du = \frac{1}{2x}dx$. Hence:

$$\int_{0}^{e^2} \frac{f(ln(\sqrt{x}))}{x}dx = 2\lim\limits_{b \to 0} \int_{\ln{\sqrt{b}}}^{1} f(u)du=2e$$

We note that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\ dx= \lim\limits_{b \to 0}\int_{b}^{1} f(x)dx = 4e$.

Is this solution valid?

Comment: only if you note the limit as the right side limit, it looks fine to me.
edit: Did you correctly multiplied the constant?

Comment: I'm quite sure that the lower limit of the second integral is $1$ and not $0$. Btw., in your substitution there should be the factor $2$ and not $\frac 12$.

Comment: I dont understand your first comment: I am substituting the bounds $u = \ln(\sqrt{e^2})$ and $u = \ln(\sqrt{0})$ ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in the problem.

There's no way to calculate the value of $\int_0^{e^2} \frac{f(\ln(\sqrt x))}{x}\,dx$ knowing the value of $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$.

To prove that observe that $f(\ln(\sqrt x))$ evaluates $f$ at negative values since $\ln(\sqrt x)$ is negative for $x \in (0,1)$. That means that $\int_0^{e^2} \frac{f(\ln(\sqrt x))}{x}\,dx$ depends on the value of $f$ at negative numbers, but $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$ doesn't.

The correct problem should say:
Find $\int_0^1 f(x) \,dx$ given $\int_1^{e^2} \frac{f(\ln(\sqrt x))}{x}\,dx = 2e$

With that correction the substitution you tried works.

Comment: This problem was presented with the typo, I was confused on how to deal with the 0.